# PCIe card memory regions ignored on linux kernel 3.13

Tags: memory, linux-kernel, pci-express

On my system, with kernel 3.13.0-32-generic (Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS) installed, one of the PCIe boards in the system (06:00.0) is having it's memory regions ignored:

```
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 10
Region 0: Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable) 
Region 2: Memory at <ignored> (32-bit, non-prefetchable)
```

In dmesg:

```
me@system:~$ dmesg | grep 06:00.0
[    1.326963] pci 0000:06:00.0: [ad00:0122] type 00 class 0x000000
[    1.326979] pci 0000:06:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7400000-0xf74001ff]
[    1.327000] pci 0000:06:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xf7200000-0xf73fffff]
```

When I subsequently try and access the board via it's kernel module, it doesn't work of course.

If I install Debian 7.5 or 7.8 on the system without changing anything else, everything works fine:

Debian:

```
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
Region 0: Memory at f7400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) 
Region 2: Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) 

me@system:~$ dmesg | grep 06:00.0
[    1.438114] pci 0000:06:00.0: [ad00:0122] type 0 class 0x000000
[    1.438130] pci 0000:06:00.0: reg 10: [mem 0xf7400000-0xf74001ff]
[    1.438151] pci 0000:06:00.0: reg 18: [mem 0xf7200000-0xf73fffff]
```

So, the hardware is fine and the issue is a combination of kernel version and the hardware.

Ubuntu kernel: 3.13.0-32-generic

Debian kernel: 3.2.0-4-amd64/

What can I do to get this working under 3.13.0-32-generic i.e. make the memory regions not be ignored?

I've tried the following with no success:

- kernel versions 3.13.11-03131111-generic and 3.16
- setting the kernel parameter mem=2048M

Many thanks!